# Simple PHP MySQL Filebrowser

Tags: php, html

I have to make a simple PHPMyAdmin Filebrowser with PHP and MySQLi.

The idea is that all databases on my local PHPMyAdmin are visible on the screen and when you click on it, that you see the tables that are in that database.

The only thing I can get working is an echo of all database names from PHPMyAdmin.

This is what I have so far:

```
<?PHP
include "connect.php";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SHOW DATABASES");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo $row[0] . "<br>";
echo '<br>';
}
?>
```

This is what I'm trying to make:

[image: Example of what i have to make]

I need help with how to make the database names clickable and when its clicked, how to make it show the tables and data in the tables.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: That's some code. The rest is applying the same pattern and rendering more HTML.

Comment: Sounds like re-inventing the `phpMyAdmin` wheels to me

Comment: @RiggsFolly As an academic project it's not the worst idea.

Comment: Thanks for your answers already but i need to know how to make the database names clickable and that it shows the tables of the clicked database

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yeah, it reminds me my early beginnings... But I started with HTML first, then learned PHP and DBs and so on...

All you need is to learn how the very basic HTML page code should looks like -  *`HTML Basics`*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
   <a href="?myName=value">This is a link</a> 
</body>
</html>
```

Then you learn how to *`send and receive data using PHP`* the data coming from the client side (web browser) to server side. So you will find out how to `$_GET` the data sent from the `anchor` such as `$_GET['myName']`

And finally study how to work with *`MySQLi prepared statement`* using object oriented `new mysqli(...)` and `$mysqli->prepare` etc.

Use search engines to search for the *`higlighted items`* to get more detailed examples.

Take it as brief guide to show you the way ;)